Whatsapp Web on Chrome/Windows: Shift+Delete not cutting to clipboard
When I press Shift + Delete I'm expecting the selected text to be cut into the clipboard. That is not happening on any text field of Whatsapp Web running on Windows/Chrome. Ctrl + X works fine though. Probably some bug with their shortcut handler.
How could I fix this?

Shift + Delete isn't currently listed as a shortcut for cut in WhatsApp Web or Windows.

@Blindspots listed where? It works everywhere on windows explorer and every website on chrome except WhatsappWeb

Windows doesn't currently list it as an alternative to cut and I've never used it  but it's behaved as you noted in many applications. There's probably a historical reason for the behavior but I'm unaware.  shift+delete a file will permanently delete it  while CTRL+X won't. If it isn't a documented function, then I wouldn't describe its absence as a bug. Web Apps are not  windows apps and their functionality & shortcuts is often different. Of course one hopes they don't make it too confusing. Alt doesn't access  menus in many Google apps as it would in most windows apps.

I'll try to learn more about it and circle back.

I posted an answer but wrote on it my phone so I may need to tweak the script later from a PC if you encounter any issues.


Source: Wikipedia > Table of keyboard shortcuts 
(Excerpted and selectively edited)
Many shortcuts are just common conventions and are not handled by the
operating system. Whether such commands are implemented depends on how
an application is written and the frameworks used. Not all follow
these conventions, so if it doesn't work, it isn't compatible.

It appears that there are a few theories as to why Shift+Del has been used as a combination for cut.
The keyboard board combination doesn't always behave as expected depending on the app and the same approach used by users to eliminate the behavior where undesirable, can be leveraged to reintroduce it where desired.
Using AutoHotKey (AHK) you could add a script that replaces that key combo for WhatsApp Web only. Something along the lines of:
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_class WhatsApp") 
+Delete::^x

Inspired by this answer
